# Div filling a table cell with 100% height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and I'm trying to get three columns filled with text overlapping a rectangle, the squares should have the same height and there must be a gutter between them.

By using the `display:table;` and `display:table-cell;` properties I have been able to make the `col-` divs to get the same height but I need the inner div to completely fill the parent and I can't see how to do this.

This is the code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="fons"></div>
    <div class="linia">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="dins">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="dins">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="dins">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.fons {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  }

.linia {
    display: table;
    margin-top:-50px;
  }

.col-md-4 {
    display: table-cell;
    float:none;
  }

.dins {
    background-color: cyan;
    padding: 15px;
  }
```

The question is: how can I get the `.dins` div to cover all the parent table cell?

Please see the sample I've made here: https://www.bootply.com/dId7aMpOcX

Comment: I realize now that not even the suggested solution works well on mobile screens

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
  .dins {
    height:100%;
    }
```

or you can use style in div instead of class

```
 <div style="height:100%">
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

use this code

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="fons">
        <table width="100%">
          <tr><td>
            <div class="linia">
     <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="dins">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
              </div></div></td>
            <td>
            <div class="linia">
     <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="dins">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
              </div></div></td>
            <td>
       <td>
            <div class="linia">
     <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="dins">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
              </div></div></td>

          </tr>
        </table>][1]][1]

</div>
```

Comment: do yo want this kind of div arrangement?

Comment: With this solution the width of the columns change according to the text length, please check the sample: https://www.bootply.com/C6MkbvQcYc

Comment: write style="width:30%" in each td.

Comment: or write <td width="30%" >

Answer (score 0):

You could add a min-height to your din classed

```
   .dins {
    background-color: cyan;
    padding: 15px;
    min-height:150px;
  }
```

or you could try one of these solutions
[How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)

Comment: I don't want to set a fixed height to that `div`because it will be defined by the inner text

Comment: it doesn't work well, I already used solution 2 of the proposed but it doesn't work well on mobile displays and the `dins` div doesn't fully cover the parent's div height

Answer (score 0):

Instead of col-md-4 you can normally put the division. Here is the code

```
<div class="linia">
  <div class="dins">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="dins">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="dins">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.linia {
 display: table;
 margin: 0px -15px;
 border-spacing: 15px;
}
.dins {
 background-color: cyan;
 padding: 15px;
 display: table-cell;
 height: 100%;
 width: 33.33334%;
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't take advantage of Bootstrap grid responsiveness

Comment: Yes but you have to make your changes for mobile using media query.

Answer (score 0):

Try using flex property :

Plunker Link : https://plnkr.co/edit/VJFOdwLjgBk9rpGP5KYQ?p=preview

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="fons"></div>
  <div class="linia">

      <div class="dins">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      </div>


      <div class="dins">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>


      <div class="dins">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.fons {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  }

.linia {
    display: flex;
    margin-top:-50px;
    box-sizing : border-box;
  }

.dins {
    background : cyan;
    margin: 15px;
    padding : 15px;
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't respect Bootstrap responsive behaviour, moreover: the column widths differ (see your Plunker)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code structure https://jsfiddle.net/c0mcwbph/

```
<div class="container">
<div class="fons"></div>
<div class="linia-wrapper">
<div class="linia">
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="dins">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="dins">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="dins">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fons { background-color: blue; }
.linia-wrapper { display: table; width: 100%; }
.linia { display: table-row; }
.col-md-4 { display: table-cell; float: none; }
.dins { background-color: cyan; padding: 15px; }
```

Comment: I see your code and the first column is taller and narrower!

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19695851/2208532) solved the issue not completely though: I had to avoid rounded corners as they weren't shown on the div's bottom.

Solution 2 (as applied in my question) seemed leaner but it didn't fully work.

Here is the solution code now working correctly: https://www.bootply.com/dId7aMpOcX